# Simple Tree Grid Example for Hilla

Tags: typescript, vaadin, hilla

Consider I have near 0% experience with typescript and now a little Hilla experience (which is going great!) please be gentle with me and provide a simple Tree Grid example.

I was hoping to do something easy like:

```
export class GroceryView extends View {
  display a lovely tree view of master detail data.
}
```

But the examples on vaadin and hilla web sites started going into which was confusing...

```
export class Example extends LitElement {}
```

I have the grid working ok.

- Looked at the various document sources and github example projects.
- I have the basic grid working ok via the View implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The `View` class in Hilla is actually an extension of `LitElement`. So if a documentation example uses `LitElement`, you can copy the contents of that class to your view and expect it to work.

The main difference between `View` and `LitElement` is that a `View` renders its template in its light DOM of the element, whereas `LitElement` by default renders its template in its shadow DOM. This is because `View` defines `createRenderRoot()` which returns `this` instead of `this.attachShadow()`.

You should be able to copy-paste the first example in the docs to your `GroceryView`: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/tree-grid

I notice now, that the examples are not showing all the needed classes in them, mainly the `DataService` and the `Person` domain object. You can copy those from the docs repo:

- https://github.com/vaadin/docs/blob/latest/frontend/demo/domain/DataService.ts
- https://github.com/vaadin/docs/blob/latest/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/domain/Person.java

Answer (score 0):

Not sure now if I need the tree grid I have manged to display the details list by calling the detailing backend `getCareersById()` and then looping to create HTML. I could not find any master/detail or tree grid examples that use a list of values from backend.

```
    careersRenderer: GridColumnBodyLitRenderer<Consultant> = (item, _model, column) => {
        return html`
        <div class="w-full flex-wrap bg-contrast-5 py-s px-l">
          ${until(getCareersById(item.careers).then(opts => repeat(opts, (career) => html`
              <h5>${career?.title}</h5>
              <p>${career?.description}</p>
            `)))}
        </div>
        `;
      };
```

[image]